# PSD to html converted Email Signature show white spaces when zoom in

Tags: html, css, html-email, psd

I have converted a template PSD Email signature to html in photoshop. when I zoom in, or insert this html signature into email (like gmail) there are lines (spaces) between the slices. please help. The HTML Code is attached. Please run in google chrome.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">
            td{line-height: 0; font-size: 0.0cm;}
            img{display:block; float:left; padding:0; align:absbottom; align:texttop; }
            
        </style>
            </head>
 <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

<table  id="Table_01" width="540" height="158" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/XFs3JK4/1-01.jpg" width="409" height="84" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/7CRmyQL/1-02.jpg" width="23" height="84" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/b3Hv5NS/1-03.jpg" width="22" height="84" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZxCjH8k/1-04.jpg" width="86" height="84" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/x5tkrHr/1-05.jpg" width="409" height="39" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PWLsbhB/1-06.jpg" width="23" height="39" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/gz8Wfs2/1-07.jpg" width="22" height="39" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6HZ3yx9/1-08.jpg" width="86" height="39" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5rDdnXV/1-09.jpg" width="409" height="35" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yF88BPb/1-10.jpg" width="23" height="35" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/4sWd88w/1-11.jpg" width="22" height="35" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tBKs4bq/1-12.jpg" width="86" height="35" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you add screenshot of lines which you are getting. i tried in gmail its works

Comment: I have attached the screenshot for reference .

Comment: added solution @tech-hub

Answer (score 0):

Added

```css
td{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">
            td{line-height: 0; font-size: 0.0cm;}
            img{display:block; float:left; padding:0; }
            
        </style>
            </head>
 <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

<table  id="Table_01" width="540" height="158" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="display:block;">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/XFs3JK4/1-01.jpg" width="409" height="84" alt=""></td>
        <td style="display:block;">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/7CRmyQL/1-02.jpg" width="23" height="84" alt=""></td>
        <td style="display:block;">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/b3Hv5NS/1-03.jpg" width="22" height="84" alt=""></td>
        <td style="display:block;">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZxCjH8k/1-04.jpg" width="86" height="84" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="display:block;">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/x5tkrHr/1-05.jpg" width="409" height="39" alt=""></td>
        <td style="display:block;">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PWLsbhB/1-06.jpg" width="23" height="39" alt=""></td>
        <td style="display:block;">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/gz8Wfs2/1-07.jpg" width="22" height="39" alt=""></td>
        <td style="display:block;">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6HZ3yx9/1-08.jpg" width="86" height="39" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="display:block;">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5rDdnXV/1-09.jpg" width="409" height="35" alt=""></td>
        <td style="display:block;">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yF88BPb/1-10.jpg" width="23" height="35" alt=""></td>
        <td style="display:block;">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/4sWd88w/1-11.jpg" width="22" height="35" alt=""></td>
        <td style="display:block;">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tBKs4bq/1-12.jpg" width="86" height="35" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That might work for some clients, but you should always inline the CSS for the rest. This is crazy email world where we love to delete embedded CSS, amongst other quirks!

Comment: Agree with this

Comment: same style can apply inline to all `td`

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I will inform after applying it.

Comment: The issue is not resolved, even after applying inline CSS to all td. Stills shows white spaces (lines) when we zoom at different levels.

Comment: check snippet. i am not able to get this lines even after zoom at 150%. where you are getting this ?

Answer (score 0):

If images are showing white lines it means you are missing `display:block` on your images. You need to add it inline. I have removed the CSS for `td` and image as I have moved it inline.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">
            td{line-height: 0; font-size: 0.0cm;}
            img{display:block; float:left; padding:0; align:absbottom; align:texttop; }
            
        </style>
            </head>
 <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

<table  id="Table_01" width="540" height="158" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/XFs3JK4/1-01.jpg" width="409" height="84" alt="" style="display:block;border:0px;"></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/7CRmyQL/1-02.jpg" width="23" height="84" alt="" style="display:block;border:0px;"></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/b3Hv5NS/1-03.jpg" width="22" height="84" alt="" style="display:block;border:0px;"></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZxCjH8k/1-04.jpg" width="86" height="84" alt="" style="display:block;border:0px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/x5tkrHr/1-05.jpg" width="409" height="39" alt="" style="display:block;border:0px;"></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PWLsbhB/1-06.jpg" width="23" height="39" alt="" style="display:block;border:0px;"></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/gz8Wfs2/1-07.jpg" width="22" height="39" alt="" style="display:block;border:0px;"></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6HZ3yx9/1-08.jpg" width="86" height="39" alt="" style="display:block;border:0px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5rDdnXV/1-09.jpg" width="409" height="35" alt="" style="display:block;border:0px;"></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yF88BPb/1-10.jpg" width="23" height="35" alt="" style="display:block;border:0px;"></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/4sWd88w/1-11.jpg" width="22" height="35" alt="" style="display:block;border:0px;"></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tBKs4bq/1-12.jpg" width="86" height="35" alt="" style="display:block;border:0px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```